# Vue-Select: Getting object selected value through page via POST method

Tags: php, html, forms, vuejs2, vue-select

This is my reproduced code.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lokasi_select: '',
    lokasi_id: '',
    lokasi_list: [{
        id_Location: 'LOC0001',
        nama_Location: 'Indonesia'
      },
      {
        id_Location: 'LOC0002',
        nama_Location: 'China'
      },
      {
        id_Location: 'LOC0003',
        nama_Location: 'America'
      },
    ],
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='app' class="form-group my-5 mx-5">
  <form method='post' action='action.php'>
    <label for="lokasi_id" class="control-label required">
      <strong>Lokasi</strong></label>
    <v-select id='lokasi_id' label='nama_Location' v-model='lokasi_select' name="lokasi_select" :options="lokasi_list" placeholder='Ketik lokasi..'>
      <span slot="no-options">Lokasi tidak ditemukan.</span>
    </v-select>

    <p>What you selected: {{lokasi_select}}</p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-select/2.5.1/vue-select.js"></script>
```

**What I wanted to do**

1. User input and select the values.
2. `lokasi_select` become an object and populated with the value of user's selected input.
3. User click submit. Moved to `action.php`.
4. `action.php` retrieve the value.

Get the value of the selected object, in this case it's `lokasi_select` then retrieve it in another page, be noted this is a form through POST method, which loads to the next page. I'm not using AJAX, cause I want to re-validate the user input on the next page. Like showing the receipt.

**What's actually happened**

1. User input and select the values.
2. `lokasi_select` become an object and populated with the value of user's selected input.
3. User click submit. Moved to `action.php`.
4. $_POST returns an array of NULL.

Now this is what my `action.php` looks like.

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST) //Returns array(0) { }
?>
```

**How could this be done?** I'm open to alternative. But not AJAX. It has to reload to the next page. Also, if I can't pass an object, then only the value of `id_Location` is fine. Cause I had a hard time finding out how to make it pass to `id_Location` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By referring to [this issue](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/102), I think you need add `hidden` inputs as below.
I have confirmed PHP can receive post values by this code.

```
<div id='app' class="form-group my-5 mx-5">
  <form method='post' action='action.php'>
    <label for="lokasi_id" class="control-label required">
    <strong>Lokasi</strong></label>
    <v-select id='lokasi_id' label='nama_Location' v-model='lokasi_select' name="lokasi_select" :options="lokasi_list" placeholder='Ketik lokasi..'>
      <span slot="no-options">Lokasi tidak ditemukan.</span>
    </v-select>
    <input type="hidden" v-model="lokasi_select.id_Location" name="id_Location" />
    <input type="hidden" v-model="lokasi_select.nama_Location" name="nama_Location" />

    <p>What you selected: {{lokasi_select}}</p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-select/2.5.1/vue-select.js"></script>
```

```
<?php
    // Returns like
    // "array(2) { ["id_Location"]=> string(7) "LOC0001" ["nama_Location"]=> string(9) "Indonesia" }"
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Wah.. Thanks! I've been looking for this like a week! It's probably because I don't know how to type the things I wanted to do..

Comment: Would you mind telling me what's actually wrong? I don't get it when the issued says `The component itself isn't a form input, so you'll need to use a hidden input.`, I guess I know that now I have to use hidden input for it. But why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this issue, but I suppose hidden input is required because select box of vue-select don't include `name` attribute

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that explains a bit why my other VueJS input can go pass, but only vue-select's input is always NULL when passed.